# VB.NET - Decrypting an already encrypted password from file with an aes key file

Tags: vb.net, encryption, aes

I need help converting powershell to VB.NET.

It needs privileges to carry commands out, I supply an encrypted username and password and call using Powershell using a key parameter and .aes file path.

Stage 1: GUI with calls to powershell scripts, including encrypted password.  It works but is slow calling powershell scripts.

I am converting all the functions I can to use SDK connections and want convert the decryption function to VB and not call powershell.

My encrypted password and aes key are in files. Examples found are not working for me.  Specifically, the SDK connection relies on SecureString to pass the password to the SDK connection, but it cannot convert the value to a SecureString.

I can use SecureString and during debugging cannot see a way within that method to do what was done with Powershell, grabbing the encrypted password and piping it to ConvertTo-SecureString and passing in the key parameter as my AES file.

Examples encrypting/decrypting advise regarding making it stronger, which I can  use instead, the command to connect to the SDK wants a SecureString so I have to try to get the info from the files and convert it to a SecureString but can't work out how.

I prefer reading files as I did in PS, converting to SecureString.

I have this so far, passing in my locations for the encrypted password and aes file. Debugging gets past it without issue (I believe), but I get exceptions converting to SecureString, and in a loop to append the characters, I get an exception about insufficient permissions, which leads me to believe that it isn't decrypting as I expect.

```
Private Function AESD(ByVal ciphertext As String, ByVal key As String) As String
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
    Dim SHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng
    Dim plaintext As String = ""
    Dim iv As String = ""
    Try
        Dim ivct = ciphertext.Split({"=="}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        iv = ivct(0) & "=="
        ciphertext = If(ivct.Length = 3, ivct(1) & "==", ivct(1))

        AES.Key = SHA256.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key))
        AES.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(iv)
        AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC
        Dim DESDecrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext)
        plaintext = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(DESDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Return plaintext
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

The decryption might not be the proper for the encryption.  I need it to run silently by pre storing an encrypted password for users.

[EDIT]: Here is the Powershell used to pull in the encrypted password

```
$password = Get-Content "locationtopasswordfile" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content "locationtoAESkeyfile")
$credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "domainaccount",$password
```

I used link to

1. Generate the encrypted password
2. What the above PS code was based on.

[How to Encrypt Passwords in PowerShell](https://www.altaro.com/msp-dojo/encrypt-password-powershell/)

Comment: show the good parts of the Powershell perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss I have edited now

Comment: I tried to reduce content down a bit without loosing intent.